# How can I be sure that my flag has been seen?

Tags: discussion, flags

How can I be sure that a moderator of a site has checked my flag and did they take any action? Is there any way to know?

I flagged a post some days ago and still I am seeing the post (the post wasn't good out of context). How can I ask a moderator to delete the post?